# Graph connection

Tags: java, graph, compiler-errors

--I have written the code for graph being connected or not.

--I am getting a compilation error for this line valueInList = (Integer) adjacencyList[i].next(); saying method next() is not defined for ArrayList

--How to fix this?

```
private boolean checkCondition2(ArrayList<Integer> [] adjacencyList,int no_of_vertices){
        int i,valueInList;
        boolean checkFlag;
        tempList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        tempList.add(1);
        for(i=0;i<no_of_vertices-1;i++){
            checkFlag = false;
            Iterator<Integer> itr = adjacencyList[i].iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                valueInList = (Integer) adjacencyList[i].next();
                if(!tempList.contains(valueInList)){
                    tempList.add(valueInList);
                    checkFlag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(checkFlag==false)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Iterator` itself instead of elements from the array

```
valueInList = itr.next();
```

Note: No casting is required as you're using a generic type for the Iterator

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList does not have "next()" method, iterator has, so instead of

```
valueInList = (Integer) adjacencyList[i].next();
```

you should have

```
valueInList = (Integer) itr.next();
```